# how to deploy apps developed in virtual env

Tags: python, module, virtualenv

I have a flask based app, and it's now running with virtualenv on my dev machine. Now I want to deploy it to my virtual host. Sadly, this virtual host is running flask 0.6, and I want flask 0.10. I don't have enough privilege to upgrade it.

Can I just upload my whole virtual environment, and to use my own version of flask, and how?

My idea is change the PYTHONPATH, how to get rid of the old version and add the new into it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: plz elaborate on who your host is and some things about them.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading your virtualenv probably won't work.  There is a good chance that something in the virtualenv is dependent on the exact file paths and versions that won't match from your machine to the virtual host.

You can upload the virtualenv tool, make a new virtualenv, and then install the version of flask you want inside that virtualenv.

Comment: thanks for reply Josshua, the problem is the host only provide wsgi to users, I can only run my application this way:

from myapp import app
import flask

application = appengine.create_wsgi_app(app)

how can I use the module I uploaded instead of the module the host provides

Comment: You probably should state what host you are using then.